# Format data using pivot table in MS Excel 2010 using c#.net

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table

I have a Excel sheet containing too much raw data. Now I want to change the representation of the data in specific format in another Excel sheet in same workbook using Pivot Table facility.

As of now to represent the data in required format I am doing few manual steps in Excel, which are mentioned below as such steps provide me resultant Format required by Client:

1. Select the sheet
2. Insert Tab --> Pivot Table
3. Create Pivot Table Dialog    Appear:Select a Table from the source sheet (Choose the data you want to analyze = Sheet1!$A:$I)
4. Select New Sheet where we want the pivot table report to be placed.
5. Select fields to add to reports- Field 1,Field 2,Field 3,Field 4,Field 5,Field 6,Field 7,Field 8,Field 9- As Row Labels
6. Pivot Table tools in Ribbon--> Options--> Deselect '+/- Buttons'
7. Pivot Table tools in ribbon--> Design --> Report Layout --> Show in tabular form
8. Pivot table tools in ribbon--> Design -->SubTotatls--> Do not show Subtotals
9. Pivot table tools in ribbon--> Design --> Grand Totals--> Off for Rows and Columns

the Source Format of excel sheet is mentioned below

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcenC.png)

Now I want to do all these manual steps programmatically using C#.net. the end result should be in Following format:

[Resultant Format- Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5O31.png)

Please mention source code to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Test.xlsx");

            Excel.Worksheet excelworksheet = excelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;

            Excel.Worksheet sheet2 = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add(); // Added new sheet to create Pivot Table
            sheet2.Name = "Pivot Table"; // Assigned sheet Name
            excelworksheet.Activate();

            Excel.Range oRange = excelworksheet.UsedRange;
            Excel.PivotCache oPivotCache = (Excel.PivotCache)excelWorkBook.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, oRange);  // Set the Source data range from First sheet
            Excel.Range oRange2 = sheet2.Cells[1, 1];
            Excel.PivotCaches pch = excelWorkBook.PivotCaches();
            pch.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, oRange).CreatePivotTable(sheet2.Cells[1, 1], "PivTbl_1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);// Create Pivot table
            Excel.PivotTable pvt = sheet2.PivotTables("PivTbl_1") as Excel.PivotTable;

            pvt.ShowDrillIndicators = false;  // Used to remove the Expand/ Collapse Button from each cell

            Excel.PivotField fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("ColumnA")); // Create a Pivot Field in Pivot table
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField; // Add the pivot field as Row Field
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false); //Remove Subtotals for each row and column 
            fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("ColumnB"));
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);
            fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("ColumnC"));
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);
            fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("ColumnD"));
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);
            fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("ColumnE"));
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);
            fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("ColumnF"));
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);
            fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("ColumnG"));
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);
            fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("ColumnH"));
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);
            fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("ColumnI"));
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField; // Sort column set as datafield to show the Pivot table as per requirement- It will show the total count of data and not needed so later on we will hide this Column

            sheet2.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit();  // Used to Autoset the column width according to data 

            //Set Conditional Formating for "Access" Column if Cell of the Access Column Contain W then Set Background color Light Green/ If R then Set Misty Rose Cell's Back Ground Color
            Excel.FormatCondition SetBgColorForAccessW = sheet2.get_Range("H:H", Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "w", Excel.XlContainsOperator.xlContains, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            SetBgColorForAccessW.Interior.Color = Color.LightGreen;
            Excel.FormatCondition SetBgColorForAccessR = sheet2.get_Range("H:H", Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "r", Excel.XlContainsOperator.xlContains, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            SetBgColorForAccessR.Interior.Color = Color.MistyRose;

            sheet2.get_Range("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = true; // Used to hide Sort Column as not needed and not have relavent data

            pvt.ColumnGrand = false;  // Used to hide Grand total for columns
            pvt.RowGrand = false; // Used to hide Grand total for Rows

            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;  // Used to hide unappropriate message prompt from Excel
            excelworksheet.Delete(); // Delete the Sheet with Raw data because not needed and we created new sheet which represent data in pivot table format
            sheet2.Activate(); // Set focus on Sheet Containing data in Pivot table format
            sheet2.get_Range("J1", "J1").Select(); // Set focus of column J to hide Pivot Table Field List (Left pane) when we open the file
            excelWorkBook.SaveAs(OutputPath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);// Used to Save as and overwrite the Excel file if already exist
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = true;  // Reset the property of Excel
            excelWorkBook.Close(); // Close the workbook
            excelApp.Quit(); // Quit the Excel application;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it helped me aswell. how can i collapse the rows?