# Generate pivottable for multiple tabgles

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, closedxml, epplus-4

good day
i have following information in my sheets:

1. information about events (id, date, name, etc)
2. list of users (id, name)
3. list of participants (id, name)
4. list of user linked to event (id, eventid, userid)
5. list of participant linked to event (id, eventid, participantid)

i need to generate pivot table based on this information (so user can create report for users on events or participants on events

i know how to do this in excel manually (i need to setup relation between tables (set primary and foreign key in tables) and after this i can select table in workbook as datasource for pivot table

but i can't do this in code. i try to use ClosedXML and EPPlus, but can't find any possibility to create relationship between table. also i can't find any way to create pivottable based on multiple table in workbook.

i try to create document manually and after that load it via library. 
document loaded via closedxml does not contains any pivot table
document loaded via epplus contain pivot table with cachesourcetype = external, but i cant create such object manualy

may be i miss something or you can tell me another library which help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format data using pivot table in MS Excel 2010 using c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523958/format-data-using-pivot-table-in-ms-excel-2010-using-c-net)

Comment: no, this is another task - i need to create pivot table from multiple linked table